# How to convert a PySpark RDD to a Dataframe with unknown columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I am creating an `RDD` by loading the data from a text file in `PySpark`. Now I want to convert this `RDD` into a `dataframe` but I do not know how many and what columns are present in the `RDD`. I am trying to use `createDataFrame()` and syntax shown for it is `sqlDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)`. I tried to see how to create the `schema` but most of the examples show a hardcoded schema creation example. Now since I do not know what are the columns so how can I convert the `rdd` into a `dataframe`? Here is my code so far:

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

example_rdd = sc.textFile("\..\file1.csv")
               .map(lambda line: line.split(",")) 

#convert the rdd into a dataframe
# df = sc.createDataFrame() # dataframe conversion here.
```

**NOTE 1:** The reason I do not know the columns is because I am trying to create a general script that can create dataframe from an RDD read from any file with any number of columns.

**NOTE 2:** I know there is another function called `toDF()` that can convert RDD to dataframe but wuth that too I have the same issue as how to pass the unknown columns.

**NOTE3:** The file format is not just a csv file. I have shown it for an example but it can be any file of any format

Comment: Why don't you just create arbitrary placeholders for the column names. Say if the expected dimensions of the data are n columns, then something like `cols = ["col".join(str(i)) for i in range(n)]`.

Comment: Also, for your schema, when you're intorducing your data to your script, you should establish a way to detect data types such as `types = [type(i) for i in data]` where data is just a place holder stuff you're reading.

Comment: @Jon How do I know what is the value of n? I mean in file there can be 10 column but in another file there can be 15

Comment: That's pretty trivial don't you think? If you're reading data from a csv file, you can parse by "," then count the number of items in the header list, such as `n = len(row[0]) `

Comment: @Jon I am pretty new and rookie to python and pyspark so if its possible you can explain it through a sample answer example it will be great to understand

Comment: I used to be a spark developer and cloud solutions "expert". If you're learning Python (or programming in general), you may want to go through some tutorials first. Spark, as much as it is marketed as a simple solution to big data problems, can be quite complex if you don't have the background for it. If you're doing this as learning exercise, that's fine, but if you're trying to deploy this in production then you may want a more seasoned programmer to review your code.

Comment: @Jon I am doing this as a learning exercise but I want to make sure that I cover a general scenario and thats why I mentioned that columns are unknown and file format is not just csv. I can covert rdd to dataframe using createDataFrame if the columns are known but I want to generalize it for unknown columns

Answer (score 4):

Spark 2.0.0 onwards supports reading csv directly as a DataFrame. In order to read a csv, use the [DataFrameReader.csv](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframereader#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader) method

```
df = spark.read.csv("\..\file1.csv", header=True)
```

In your case, if you do not have access to spark object, you can use,

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.csv("\..\file1.csv", header=True)
```

In case the file has a different separator, you can specify that too.

```
# Eg if separator is ::
df = spark.read.csv("\..\file1.csv", head=True,sep="::")
```

Comment: that I know but csv is not the only file format I will be reading and thats why I am not using read_csv().

Comment: Do you have access to spark 2.0.0 or greater ? I can provide a code sample.

Comment: I do not have access to 2.0.0 but can the DataFrameReader.csv method read a non csv file as well?

Comment: the reason I am not using a inherent csv reader is because csv is not the only file format I will be working with. It can be a simple txt file too with some other delimiter instead of a ,

Comment: Using `sep` parameter should help you as shown in the answer.

Comment: my doubt is will it work if the filename is say file.txt instead of file1.csv?

Comment: It should. I would encourage you to give it a try. Read a csv file named as `file.txt` and do a `df.show()` to see if it worked or not. Feel free to update your question, in case you get an error.